# JPA In Query as list of string not giving answer

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

```
List<Thing> results = em.createQuery(
"select t from Thing t where t.status in ('A', 'E')")
.getResultList();
```

This is using create query and without parameter.And it works fine

```
List<String> statusList= new ArrayList<String>();
statusList.add("A");
statusList.add("E");

 List<Thing> results = em.createQuery(
"select t from Thing t where t.status in ('"+statusList.toSting()+"')")
.getResultList();
```

This is not working .I don't want IN(:parameter)  to set .Only I need in the above descried one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it like above You have to use `in` as below

```
Query query=em.createQuery(
"select t from Thing t where t.status in (:list)")
query.setParameterList("list", statusList)
query.getResultList();
```

Your `statusList.toSting()` will not produce a string like `'A','E'` becuase you have added the `statusList.toSting()` in `()` so if your ultimate result will looks like `('A','E')` then only your query will give correct results

Comment: Is there any possible solution without setting parameter list

Comment: @muthukumar you can prepare a comma seperated values of contenets of the list i,e like A,E,B,D..... and after that you can put this in `in clause`

Comment: `for(String content:statusList) { contents+=content+","}` and can use `em.createQuery(
"select t from Thing t where t.status in +contents+")
.getResultList();`